# Win Form: Multiple-choice button

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have a button having multiple options. I mean, its like a combobox having buttons inserted in it. My intention is to create a button which doing two things according to choice: "Load Setting" or "Restore last setting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use something like a [SplitButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597320/split-button-in-net-winforms).  If that's not what you want, you can always have a combobox full of options with a button below it, or a radiobutton group... or even just multiple buttons.