# How can I create a button with a dropdown arrow near it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I did :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int x, y;
        private int gap = 0;
        private int startingY = 83;
        private GroupBox lastGB = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Text = "Details " + char.ConvertFromUtf32(8595);
        }
```

The result is something bad not looking good :

[image: my button]

This is what I want to make : The NEW is acting like a button it is a button. The arrow near it is like a combobox :

[image: The button with arrow I want]

If I click on the NEW it will open folder dialog if I click on the arrow it will open kind of combobox without the borders.

Comment: it seems you need two buttons, placed one beside the other. for the arrow button, use the image button to place the arrow and leave it with no text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called `SplitButton`. This question has been asked few times over the years.

You can draw an inspiration from the [Windows Forms codebase](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/46cd3ca36be6fe6107ea38edece3639be75fd045/src/System.Windows.Forms.Design/src/System/ComponentModel/Design/CollectionEditor.cs#L426). 
Or look at other answers to the same question: [Split button in .NET Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597320/split-button-in-net-winforms).
Or search online for `SplitButton`.